# In a galvanic/voltaic cell diagram, does convention require for the anode to be on the left?

Tags: electrochemistry

It seems as though in every diagram, illustration, and demonstration I've seen of a voltaic cell, the anode is placed on the left and the cathode is placed on the right. Is this a rule, or a convention? Would it be frowned upon to publish a diagram where the cathode is placed left of the anode?

Comment: It's apparently from a 1953 IUPAC recommendation, referenced [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=x6ct1xjyJpoC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=diagram++anode+on+left+side+iupac&source=bl&ots=uFZxTBxaQ5&sig=ACfU3U2rmBpQlOo0Pk7do4HM0Lp4H9bNWQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyy-Cm5eT0AhWEmGoFHVcPCC0Q6AF6BAgpEAM#v=onepage&q=diagram%20%20anode%20on%20left%20side%20iupac&f=false) and [here](https://old.iupac.org/publications/analytical_compendium/Cha01sec310.pdf). I, for one, would frown upon what you propose if I were a referee.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such rule that in a schematic/illustration/cartoon of a galvanic or an electrolytic cell the anode should be on the left or on the right. The electrons do not care nor the electrolytic reactions depend on how *humans* show pictorial galvanic cell schematics.

However you will notice that when electrochemists describe a galvanic cell in a very specific *notation*, there is a common agreement among them.

***R**eduction is always shown on the **r**ight hand side* and this is how I remember it, which means anode or oxidation must be written on the left as follows.

[image: pic]

See Wikipedia for more examples [Cell notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_notation). Single bar shows a phase boundary and the two vertical bars indicate a salt bridge.

If you are just drawing beakers for just an galvanic/electrolytic cell, it does not matter whether right electrode is the cathode or not. All we have to do is to label the diagram correctly.

Comment: See also the [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anode#Etymology) and Faraday's East-West mnemotechnic reasoning. It may be the convention since then.

Comment: Quoting Wikipedia link above:  *.....In that paper Faraday explained that when an electrolytic cell is oriented so that electric current traverses the "decomposing body" (electrolyte) in a direction "from East to West, or, which will strengthen this help to the memory, that in which the sun appears to move", the anode is where the current enters the electrolyte, on the East side: "ano upwards, odos a way; the way which the sun rises".  The use of 'East' to mean the 'in' direction (actually 'in' → 'East' → 'sunrise' → 'up') may appear contrived. ......*

Comment: P.S.: So perhaps a long standing history-based habit than mandatory convention.

Comment: Similar to catod and anod in relation to material falling or be taken up. So that the terms are somewhat confusing

Answer (score 1):

When plotted on a horizontal $0x$ axis, with the zero point at some arbitrary point, the positive numbers are always on the right-hand side of the zero point. And the negative numbers are on the left-hand side of the Zero point. This is arbitrary, but universally respected, in mathematics and in all other common applications.

The same convention is applied for reduction potentials. When reported on a horizontal scale, with Hydrogen in the middle, negative redox potentials are on the left-hand side of hydrogen, like zinc (at -$0.76$ V). And positive reduction potentials are on the right-hand side of the horizontal scale, like Copper (at $+0.34$ V).

With this convention, electrons are running from left to right, from the most negative electrode (anode) to the most positive electrode (cathode). Electrons are running by alphabetic order, from A(node) to C(cathode)